# Fitness HistoryClient says "The user must be signed in to make this API call."

Tags: android, google-fitness-api

I need to use the Fitness HistoryClient (Fitness.getHistoryClient). When I do so I keep getting an error that says "The user must be signed in to make this API call".

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. My code requests the ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission, and it also obtains the account via a call to "GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)", which I've confirmed is not null. What am I missing?

Frank